# Counter increment ++ wrong number

Tags: php

```
<?php
   $counter = 'www.mywebsite.com/counter/counter.txt';
   $download = 'www.mywebsite.com/file/1.pdf';

   $number = file_get_contents($counter); // read count file 
   $number++; // increment count by 1 
   $fh = fopen($counter, 'w'); // open count file for writing 
   fwrite($fh, $number); // write new count to count file 
   fclose($fh); // close count file 
   header("Location: $download"); // get download 

?>
```

Why the number counter after ex:5,999 restart at 5000??? and not to 6,000???

Comment: We do not know what's in those files, how can we help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $counter = 'www.mywebsite.com/counter/counter.txt';
    $download = 'www.mywebsite.com/file/1.pdf';

    $number = intval(file_get_contents($counter)); // read count file 
    $number++; // increment count by 1 
    $fh = fopen($counter, 'w'); // open count file for writing 
    fwrite($fh, $number); // write new count to count file 
    fclose($fh); // close count file 
    header("Location: $download"); // get download
```

?>

!!! intval()... Fixed.